# Bayes' Theory Fundementals

Tags: probability, bayesian

I saw an equation as like that:

$$P(W) = P(W\mid R,S)+P(W\mid !R,S) + P(W\mid !R,S) + P(W\mid R,!S) + P(W\mid !R,!S)$$

Which of these two statements are true?

$$P(W) = P(W\mid R,S)P(R,S)+P(W\mid !R,S)\,P(!R,S) + P(W\mid !R,S)\,P(!R,S) + P(W\mid R,!S)\,P(R,!S) + P(W\,!R,!S)\,P(!R,!S)$$
or
$$P(R,S) = P(R\mid S)\,P(S) = P(S\mid R)\,P(R).$$

Is there any document for it?

Comment: There are $5$ terms in the expressions on the right side of $P(W)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More specifically, you saw that equation in my flawed answer to [this question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234324), which I've now corrected. Your second version is correct.

You could have asked that question as a comment under my answer, or at least linked to that answer. In case you didn't do that so as not to offend me by implying that I made a mistake, there's no need for such restraint – [errare humanum est](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errare_humanum_est#errare_humanum_est) :-)

Comment: ... *perseverare diabolicum*. :-)

Comment: @joriki I asked this as a separate question because I wanted to learn underlying equation for it. On the other hand I accepted your answer as correct because I don't know anything about that equations, I didn't want to show your mistake :)